# Updating the text content file in xml

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, dom

I have an xml file.the thing is if the user is block i want to change the status to blocked and change it completely to xml. i want to update the text Active in status to Blocked without using input type.just changed it to blocked.Can someone help me?Thank you for your help

here is my xml file

```
<users>
    <user>
        <username>A</username>
        <password>12344</password>
        <status>Active</status>
    </user>
</users>
```

Comment: can you explain your question please, I can't understand it

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve].

Comment: @AlameerAshraf for example i want to login.The status of the user is Active. I have a condition where u can input 3 attempts in my login. if the user tries to login but she login 3 times the user that try to login will be blocked. What i want to say is i want to change the status of user to Blocked. if she login 3 attempts.

Comment: @AlameerAshraf for example i will login the username of A. I will login A 3 times with wrong password. after that 3 times the status="Active" will change to status="Blocked" in xml.

Comment: Are you trying to use an XML file as a database? Thats a bad idea, but any answer would depend on your server side environment.